# Access another variable from another method with random value

Tags: c#

I've created a List of Integers. I've created a method to pick a random number from the list and output it using a textbox. Once it is picked in the List, it will be remove so that there will be no repetition. Here's my code:

```
private void clickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnCase.Text == "")
    {
        lblSelectedCase.Text = "Your Briefcase:";
        lblCasesToOpen.Visible = true;
        lblNumber.Visible = true;
        lblNumber.Text = myGame.counter.ToString();
        btnCase.Visible = true;
        btnCase.Text = ((Button)sender).Text;
        ((Button)sender).Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        lblNumber.Text = myGame.decreaseCounter().ToString();
        num = myGame.showAmount();

        var selected = MessageBox.Show("Briefcase amount: $" + num.ToString(), "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        if (selected == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _label[num].Visible = false;
            myGame.removeAmount();
            ((Button)sender).Visible = false;
        }

        if(myGame.counter == 0)
        {
            foreach (Button button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
            {
                button.Enabled = false;
            }

            myGame.computeAverage();
            lblBankerOffer.Visible = true;
            lblOffer.Visible = true;
            lblOffer.Text = "$" + myGame.bankerOffer().ToString();
            btnDeal.Visible = true;
            btnNoDeal.Visible = true;
            lblCasesToOpen.Visible = false;
            lblNumber.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}

private void btnNoDeal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myGame.turn == 9)
    {
        int n = num;
        var winnings = MessageBox.Show("You won: $" + n.ToString(), "Congratulations", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        if (winnings == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (n > myData.Score)
            {
                myData.Score = myGame.showAmount();
                myData.updateScore();
            }

            this.Hide();

            frmHome _frmHome = new frmHome(myData.User.ToString(), myData.FName.ToString(), myData.LName.ToString(), myData.Score);

            _frmHome.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
            _frmHome.Show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (Button button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            button.Enabled = true;
        }

        lblNumber.Text = myGame.showCounter().ToString();
        lblBankerOffer.Visible = false;
        lblOffer.Visible = false;
        btnDeal.Visible = false;
        btnNoDeal.Visible = false;
        lblCasesToOpen.Visible = true;
        lblNumber.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

I want to access the part where `num = myGame.showAmount();` on the clickHandler method to my btnNoDeal_Click because I'm having a problem once the turn == 9, a MessageBox will appear, giving me a value that has been already used.

Edit: The show amount method is a random generated number from the list:

```
public int showAmount()
{
    index = _random.Next(0, amounts.Count);
    return amounts[index];
}
```

Comment: so what happens when you call this ` num = myGame.showAmount();` have you stepped through your own code ..? also what's your question.. what you what to do is not a question

Comment: @MethodMan It will call this method public int showAmount()
        {
            index = _random.Next(0, amounts.Count);
            return amounts[index];
        }

Comment: so what the value of `amounts[index]` when you step past it when setting a breakpoint on `}`